# Where do I find the Manage External User Button on the Contact Page Layout

Tags: page-layout, button

This question has not been answered elsewhere.

Salesforce Documents suggest there is a Manage External User Button.

But it cannot be found in the Contact Page Layout Editor.

Where Is It?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Manage External User Button.

Look for these types Buttons and Actions instead:
Enable Disable Login... etc

- Enable Customer User
- View Customer User
- Disable Customer USer
- Log in to Community as User

Answer (score 0):

Check this Knowledge Article:

[Unable to see the 'Manage External Users' Button in Contact layout](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213565&type=1)

Comment: This Link you share is the Salesforce Document that is Incorrect.
There is no such button as 'Manage External Users'

Comment: @NZDev in Classic UI, there is "Manage External Users" button from which you can access the next level of buttons: e.g. enable community user, Login in to Community User. In Lightning UI, yes, there is no this button

Comment: The Document you posted says this:
Click on Setup | Customize | Contacts | Page Layouts
On the "Quick Find" box, type in Manage External Button
Once found drag it to the button section on page layout

This is incorrect, and hence I re-iterate there is no Manage External Users button, it cannot be found in the Contact Page Layout Editor

Comment: The point I am raising is that this specific documentation is flawed, the whole reason for this post was because of that document being incorrect. And if another person was to search this same problem they would find very little about it.

Answer (score 0):

Manage External User Button is available on Contact object
1. Enable Communities
2. Check that Contact is associated to a contact
3. Button will added to page layout

[image]